# DELETE specific rows that matches all values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Say I have a table

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM (
  VALUES ('col1_a', 'col2_a', 'col3_a', 'coln_a'),
         ('col1_b', 'col2_b', 'col3_b', 'coln_b'),
         ('col1_c', 'col2_c', 'col3_c', 'coln_c')
) t (col1, col2, col3, coln)
```

I only want to delete rows that matches with every single column values I specific (consider rows are highly similar only one or two columns are different)

Of course I can write

```
DELETE MyTable WHERE col1='col1_a' AND col2='col2_a' AND col3='col3_a' AND coln='coln_a'
DELETE MyTable WHERE col1='col1_b' AND col2='col2_b' AND col3='col3_b' AND coln='coln_b'
```

But thats too annoying. I want to know if it is possible to write it conveniently by simply listing out the values? I tried this

```
DELETE MyTable FROM (
  VALUES ('col1_a', 'col2_a', 'col3_a', 'coln_a'),
         ('col1_b', 'col2_b', 'col3_b', 'coln_b')
) t (col1, col2, col3, coln)
```

but that just removed all the rows in MyTable, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` on your `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE t1
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('col1_a', 'col2_a', 'col3_a', 'coln_a'),
        ('col1_b', 'col2_b', 'col3_b', 'coln_b')
    )AS a(col1, col2, col3, coln)
) t2
    ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
    AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
    AND t2.col3 = t1.col3
```

---

As commented by [Frisbee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607314/frisbee), you can remove the `SELECT *`:

```
DELETE t1
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES 
        ('col1_a', 'col2_a', 'col3_a', 'coln_a'),
        ('col1_b', 'col2_b', 'col3_b', 'coln_b')    
) AS t2(col1, col2, col3, coln)
    ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
    AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
    AND t2.col3 = t1.col3
```

Comment: Thanks. I reckon yours is the same approach as mine but with join. Any reason why mine didn't work without a join?

Comment: Since the target of your `DELETE` is `MyTable` and there is no condition that links `MyTable` with `t`, all rows of `MyTable` gets deleted.

Comment: Additionally, when linking one table to another on `DELETE` statement, the tables must be in `FROM` or in `JOIN`. However, the target of the `DELETE` statement is the table that comes after the `DELETE` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. Can you think of another way to avoid the joining conditions? For n columns, this is still ugly. Something like replacing MyTable with MyTable EXCEPT VALUES?

Comment: I don't think you need the select  * from